# how to replace special characters in bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have two problems. I have an input like this

```
foo.o
bar.o
```

I need to replace the dot with a character of my choice (in this case it is "D") and I need to append "] at the end of each line.

I know how to append ] with awk

```
awk '{print $0"]"}'
```

but I dont know how to add " as well, my simple attempt was

```
  awk '{print $0""]"}'
```

but as expected that doesnt work.

Also I don't know how to replace the dot at all.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` is a regex metacharacter.  Put it within a character class:

```
awk '{gsub("[.]", "D", $0)}{print $0"]"}'
```

or *double escape* it:

```
awk '{gsub("\\.", "D", $0)}{print $0"]"}'
```

For adding the quote, escape it.  In order to add, `"]`, say:

```
print $0"\"]"
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 'y/./D/;s/$/]/' input.txt 
fooDo]
barDo]
$
```

- `y/./D/` replaces all instances of "." with "D".  The `y` command is a simple string replacement and not a regexp replacement, so the `.` doesn't need any special escaping in this command.
- `s/$/]/` matches the end of the line and effectively appends "]".